# Interaction between custom forms and event recievers

Tags: custom-form, event-receivers

How can we interect with custom forms and event recievers? How can we talk to custom fields (asp controls) within the custom form from an event recievers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't talk to the fields. The custom forms are simply a way to add / update list items (which can also be done through a large number of other ways). The event receiver simply allows you access the list item data during the process of adding / updating it.